# How to count the last records of a given status?

Tags: sql, count

I need to count the last few months a member has had a D status.

For example, I have the table below, where I have the months from February to August for 2 members.

| year_month | member_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020_02 | 1010 | D |
| 2020_03 | 1010 | D |
| 2020_04 | 1010 | D |
| 2020_05 | 1010 | A |
| 2020_06 | 1010 | A |
| 2020_07 | 1010 | D |
| 2020_08 | 1010 | D |
| 2020_02 | 1030 | A |
| 2020_03 | 1030 | A |
| 2020_04 | 1030 | A |
| 2020_05 | 1030 | D |
| 2020_06 | 1030 | A |
| 2020_07 | 1030 | A |
| 2020_08 | 1030 | D |

I need to count the number of months a member has been in D status in a row. In this example the expected result would be:

| member_id | count status D |
| --- | --- |
| 1010 | 2 |
| 1030 | 1 |

For member 1010 I need to count July and August, because in June he had A status.

Can anyone help me, please?

I'm a beginner and I have no idea how I can do this.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try first filtering for each member to only latest `D` records.  Then, aggregate by members and find the counts.

```sql
SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS count_status_D
FROM
(
    SELECT member_id
    FROM yourTable t1
    WHERE status = 'D' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM yourTable t2
                      WHERE t2.member_id = t1.member_id AND
                            t2.year_month > t1.year_month AND
                            t2.status <> 'D')
) t
GROUP BY member_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL you could use for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT member_ID) AS member_ID FROM Table WHERE Status = D;
```

For more info: http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_func_count.asp.html

Comment: Your answer won't work and this isn't a beginner question.